# Is there a way to read the balance of any public address on Ethereum mainnet using Ethers?

Tags: solidity, metamask, ethers.js

I am trying to build a very simple tool as a beginner project. A user inputs a wallet address, and my site shows the ETH balance of that address.

I tried this, which worked with wallets that I had connected to the site, but not with ones that weren't. I'm assuming because `provider` has something to do only with connected wallets.

```
  async function getBalance(wallet) {
    let balance = await provider.getBalance(wallet);
    // we use the code below to convert the balance from wei to eth
    balance = ethers.utils.formatEther(balance);
    console.log(balance);
  }
```

Does metamask/ethers have a built in way to read on-chain data or do I need to go through something like the Etherscan API? I'm assuming there is something built in because I'm able to get my own balance.

Comment: That should work for every address. Are you sure it only works for wallets connected to the site?

Comment: Huh.. interesting. Yeah I'm pretty sure. I hardcoded my wallet address into the code, and then attempted to get the balance when I was connected vs not connected. I'll have to try again later today.